# I get a error "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: application-development, python

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/mybrowser", line 32, in <module>
    import mybrowser
  File "/home/shaunyo/mybrowser/mybrowser/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mybrowser import MybrowserWindow
  File "/home/shaunyo/mybrowser/mybrowser/MybrowserWindow.py", line 32
    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
                                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

This is my code:

```
    self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")

    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    print "refresh"
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your *whole* `MybrowserWindow.py` file into [here](http://mysticpaste.com/new) and then provide the link in your question. I think that (after watching the video) that there is a problem with your indentation and that the code is no longer part of the `MybrowserWindow` class

Comment: @minerz029 http://mysticpaste.com/view/hsk24ZfNo1?2

Comment: See my new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have your code like

```
<TAB> self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
<TAB> def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
<TAB> print "refresh"
```

in your editor give a <kbd>TAB</kbd> everytime while entering in a new line.

Ok @Shaun

I think your code should look like

```
frank@FRANK-NATHE:~$ cat h.py
self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
    print "refresh"
```

so don't use a tab for the 1st and 2nd lines and then use a tab for the 3rd line

If you still get confused then

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I gave it ago, and this what I got back:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/mybrowser", line 32, in <module>
    import mybrowser
  File "/home/shaunyo/mybrowser/mybrowser/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mybrowser import MybrowserWindow
  File "/home/shaunyo/mybrowser/mybrowser/MybrowserWindow.py", line 26
    <TAB> self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object ("refreshbutton")
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Shaun You should press the 'Tab' key when you see `<TAB>` and the line which says `print "refresh"` should be indented an extra tab. If you're looking for a tutorial to get started with Python, I recommend the book [A byte of Python](http://swaroopch.com/notes/python/)

Comment: @rajagenupula Hello, I've tried that, good news is that the error has disappeared. The down side is that terminal isn't printing "Refresh" when I click the button "Refresh" in quickly. Any ideas?

Comment: @Shaun well that’s come under a new problem. I am not that much expert in the python.you better go with a new post.

Comment: @Shaun I don't have much experience with GUIs in python but don't you need to connect the `on_refreshbutton_clicked()` function to your `self.refreshbutton` like this: `self.refreshbutton.connect("clicked", self.on_refreshbutton_clicked)`

Comment: @minerz029 I am following this tut (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg) go to 13:00 and he shows the coding there.

Comment: @minerz029 http://mysticpaste.com/view/hsk24ZfNo1?2 here you go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the code is with the refresh function is not being run. Try indenting [these highlighted lines](http://mysticpaste.com/view/Pm8C5zEw8P/26-29?9) an extra tab.

[image]

becomes

[image]

so that the code is run in the `finish_initializing()` function. Python is **very** particular with it's indentation

**Note** that the `self.refreshbutton` line is in line with the `# Code for other...` comment in the 2nd image

Comment: I've tried this, In terminal It's not generating "refresh".

Comment: @Shaun Can you try and indent those lines an extra tab each?

Comment: Is there any way we can communicate about this, it would witch might make my understanding much better.

Comment: @Shaun see my updated answer with images

Comment: Yes, I've did as you asked. I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Well, I cannot help you, try asking another question about this specifc problem. Sorry

Comment: No problem! I thank you for ur time and your help today, ow' ya one.